# Light on iPhone4s comes on without doing anything

Tags: iphone

Hope this is right StackExchange forum. Otherwise advise the appropriate forum.

A respected, elderly relative has iphone4s. He complains that the light suddenly comes on, even when he is not doing anything on the phone. He is concerned that someone bugged his phone. I tried googling a solution, and couldn't find anything.

(as I get more info about ios, etc, I'll post, but I think the question is general enough to start troubleshooting)

Any suggestions.

Thanks a bunch!!!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about smartphone troubleshooting.

Comment: `"but I think the question is general enough to start troubleshooting"` - That's actually the opposite of how Stack Overflow works.  We're not here for open discussions on general problems, we're here to answer specific questions.  Particularly about writing software, which this question isn't about.

Comment: @MattBall Then what is a good forum for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried hard resetting the iphone (restoring it to its factory settings).
To do so follow the following steps:

1. Backup the phone to avoid data loss.
2. Go to settings --> general --> reset
3. In the reset menu click on "Erase all content and settings" --> "Erase Phone"

Hope this would help.